# How to find the process with a page in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm working on a project about Linux kernel mm(memory management) and with a page, I need to find the process which the page belongs to.

However, I could not find any way without modifying the kernel. So, I'm really wondering whether it is possible to do that without modifying kernel.

In detail, when I have a VMA then, it is also possible to convert the VMA into the corresponding page, I want to know what process the VMA or page belongs to.

for example, in mm/page_io.c (of linux kernel source tree):

```
    int __swap_writepage(struct page *page, struct writeback_control *wbc,
        void (*end_write_func)(struct bio *, int))
{
        struct bio *bio;
        int ret, rw = WRITE;
        struct swap_info_struct *sis = page_swap_info(page);
...
        ret = bdev_write_page(sis->bdev, swap_page_sector(page), page, wbc);
        if (!ret) {
                count_vm_event(PSWPOUT);

                /* I should figure out what process is having the page above.
                 * But it is hard to know, because page is managed in LRU and
                 * it is not directly related to its process. What hints I have
                 * are page struct and some data structures which I could
                 * infer from the page only.
                 */
```

I'm waiting for your great answer. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know enough for a great answer, but I have a suggestion: look at `/proc`.  For example, read ``/proc/nnn/maps`` for every process.

Comment: Note that memory may be shared between several processes, in that case the shared physical page will belong to several processes

Answer (score 1):

#### Process memory pages

@G-Man is correct that the `/proc` filesystem can provide you with the information.  And he is also correct that `/proc/<pid>/maps` will give some info.  For example, here is some `/proc/<pid>/maps` output:

```
7f2c09a0c000-7f2c09a0d000 r--p 00022000 08:03 3804420                    /usr/lib/ld-2.24.so
7f2c09a0d000-7f2c09a0e000 rw-p 00023000 08:03 3804420                    /usr/lib/ld-2.24.so
7f2c09a0e000-7f2c09a0f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffc46cf9000-7ffc46d1a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc46d86000-7ffc46d88000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffc46d88000-7ffc46d8a000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

The problem here is that we get the virtual pages in this output, and no relation to the physical pages can be found from there.

On the other hand, `/proc` also has a `/proc/<pid>/pagemap` which is a mapping of virtual memory into the actual memory pages (including swap).  Let's see what `man 5 proc` tells us about it:

```
/proc/[pid]/pagemap (since Linux 2.6.25)
       This  file  shows the mapping of each of the process's virtual pages into physical page frames or swap area.
       It contains one 64-bit value for each virtual page, with the bits set as follows:

            63     If set, the page is present in RAM.

            62     If set, the page is in swap space

            61 (since Linux 3.5)
                   The page is a file-mapped page or a shared anonymous page.

            60-56 (since Linux 3.11)
                   Zero

            55 (Since Linux 3.11)
                   PTE is soft-dirty (see the kernel source file Documentation/vm/soft-dirty.txt).

            54-0   If the page is present in RAM (bit 63), then these bits provide the page frame number, which can
                   be  used  to  index  /proc/kpageflags and /proc/kpagecount.  If the page is present in swap (bit
                   62), then bits 4-0 give the swap type, and bits 54-5 encode the swap offset.
```

OK, so we have one 64bit integer for each memory page, and a bunch of flags that tell us what the page does.  To read `/proc/<pid>/pagemap` we need root permissions.  Also the file is just a list of 64 bit integers so I'll use:

```
[~]# cat /proc/950/pagemap |xxd |less
...
000020c0: 0585 0600 0000 00a0 0285 0600 0000 00a0  ................
000020d0: 0385 0600 0000 00a0 6692 0600 0000 00a0  ........f.......
000020e0: 6792 0600 0000 00a0 488e 0600 0000 00a0  g.......H.......
000020f0: 498e 0600 0000 00a0 1c93 0600 0000 00a0  I...............
00002100: c45e 0600 0000 00a0 c55e 0600 0000 00a0  .^.......^......
00002110: c65e 0600 0000 00a0 c75e 0600 0000 00a0  .^.......^......
00002120: c85e 0600 0000 00a0 c95e 0600 0000 00a0  .^.......^......
00002130: ca5e 0600 0000 00a0 f05e 0600 0000 00a0  .^.......^......
00002140: f15e 0600 0000 00a0 f25e 0600 0000 00a0  .^.......^......
00002150: f35e 0600 0000 00a0 f45e 0600 0000 00a0  .^.......^......
00002160: f55e 0600 0000 00a0 f65e 0600 0000 00a0  .^.......^......
...
000035c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000035d0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000035e0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000035f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00003600: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00003610: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00003620: 0000 0000 0000 0000 c460 0400 0000 0081  .........`......
00003630: f02a 0400 0000 0081 b6f7 0100 0000 0081  .*..............
00003640: 804b 0300 0000 0081 0770 0400 0000 0081  .K.......p......
00003650: 2844 0500 0000 0081 3d9b 0400 0000 0081  (D......=.......
00003660: 192f 0400 0000 0081 813c 0300 0000 0081  ./.......<......
00003670: b1f7 0100 0000 0081 40a7 0300 0000 0081  ........@.......
00003680: ee58 0400 0000 0081 97c8 0300 0000 0081  .X..............
00003690: 9afa 0100 0000 0081 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000036a0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
000036b0: 4d80 0400 0000 0081 0bb7 0400 0000 0081  M...............
000036c0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
...
```

The output above is just from my shell process.  There is a lot of output there because it is a map of the entire memory of the process.  And all parts that are not currently mapped simply contain zeros.

Let's take the page `c85e 0600 0000 00a0` (at 0x2120 of the xxd output) which is on a little-endian machine so let's invert it to `a000 0000 0006 5ec8`.  Since the first byte is 0xa0 then the bit 63 is set, so it is a page in RAM.  The bit numbering is zero based so the bit 63 is the last bit (not the bit 64).  And the last 54 bits are 0x65ec8 (with a bunch of zeros in front) which is the index of the actual page.

Now, the page `2844 0500 0000 0081` (at 0x3650 of the xxd output) can be inverted to `8100 0000 0005 4428`.  There the first byte is 0x81 and its bit 62 is set so it is a page in SWAP.  Am not sure about the reason that bit 56 is set: maybe an something undocumented or a mistake in the man (which notes the bit 55).  Nevertheless bits 54-0 tell us other things: 0x28 gives us the swap type i.e. 0x8; and the offset is at `0x5442 >> 1` ('cause the last bit is part of the swap type) i.e. 0x2a21.

(I hope I did not screw up the flag/little-endian calculation this time.  I did screw up the bit count the first time I wrote this.)

#### Page to process problem

The only problem with the above is that that is a map of process -> page.  Not really page -> process.  But you can search every `/proc/kpagecount` to see all pages that are currently used (everything that has a count > 0, that is another list of 64 bit integers one per page).  And then search all `proc/<pid>` directories.  This becomes a problem if processes start and finish quickly so that you can't find their `/proc/<pid>`.  But that should not be important unless you're trying to enforce security policies or something similar.  (never trust `/proc` for security policies, because things change too fast).

#### Extra

Now you can use the 0x54428 index to search for the page flags in `/proc/kpageflags` it will be the `0x54428th` 64bit integer.  This is also described in `man 5 proc`.